# Why do you need to wrap containers of brined meat?

Tags: meat, seasoning, brining

Everyone says you should seal whatever container you brine your meat with using tinfoil or airtight nylon. What are the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the issues with contamination, a good tight seal helps to contain any sloshing when you're moving the container around.

This reduces the chance of spashing brine when intentionally moving the container, or when pushing it out of the way to get to something behind it.

A minute or so of prevention can save you a significant amount of time in cleaning and disinfecting every other container in your fridge, plus the fridge itself.

Answer (score 1):

It helps prevent contamination from outside sources. You don't want nasties in your brine anymore than you do in your fresh salad.

Comment: When you say contamination, you mean stuff physically falling into the brine, or aerial contamination from other foods? Because the one means sealing off with a plate on top is sufficient, while the other calls for airtight sealing.

Comment: I mean either or both